# C double character pointer declaration and initialization

Tags: c, string, pointers, initialization, declaration

I always though that declaring

```
char *c = "line";
```

was the same as

```
char c[] = "line";
```

and so I did

```
char **choices = { "New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit" };
```

Which gives me an incompatible pointer type, where

```
char *choices[] = { "New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit" };
```

doesn't. Any help on understanding this?

Comment: C arrays != C pointers.

Comment: In Example1, c is a pointer to a char.  In example2, c is an array of chars.  In Example3, choices is a pointer to a pointer to A char (and is incorrectly assigned an array of chars.)  In Example4, choices is an array of pointers to chars (and is correctly assigned an array of chars.)

Comment: @oosterwal: for **ex3** and **ex4** you said "...assigned an array of chars", but correct is "...assigned an array of pointers to chars". For the **ex3** - there is [a possibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832082/c-double-character-pointer-declaration-and-initialization/4832167#4832167) to assign an _array of pointers to chars_ using _compound literals_.

Comment: @Martin Babacaev (and anyone else who's interested):  A few years ago I came across an article on the clockwise spiral rule for figuring out what some of those strange declarations mean.  I highly recommend it to anyone who struggles with this:  http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: @oosterwal: thanks. I like this one http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html. It also explains _abstract declarations_ e.g. `int (*(*)())()`

Comment: @Martin Babacaev:  There's a lot of good stuff there.  Thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, they're not the same.  It's just easier for most people to think of them as being the same so everyone starts to think that way until they run into a problem like the above :-)

I was going to write something long and winded, but then I figured...  Someone else must have done this already.  And they have.  This is a pretty good explanation:

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

The easiest way to think about it is that when you do something like:

```
  char *foo = "something";
```

You're really doing something like:

```
  char randomblob[] = "something";
  char *foo = randomblob;
```

Now...  that's not really an accurate picture (though I'm not a compiler expert).  It at least lets you think about things in a slightly more correct fashion.

So, back to your problem, if *I* understand things right (which is never guaranteed), you can't do your example line #3 in C.  You're right that someone could write a compiler that would do the right thing here, but gcc doesn't.  The 4th example, however, does the "right thing" and gives you "an array of pointers that are each pointing to a const char array themselves".

I once ran across a web page that would translate a complex C type into English.  That was probably in the early 90s though but I bet if you google enough it would give you a more accurate wording description than the one I just whipped up.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, I always thought that arrays did the same as pointers. I guess I never really read much about arrays. For me it was always something which pointed to the first little box of memory and went from there till it got a '\0' so having one declaration or the other seemed the same. The other answers were also good but your link cleared things for me.

Comment: for this and other mistakes like this C is a sharp knife

Answer (score 18):

```
char *c = "line";
```

is *not* the same as

```
char c[] = "line";
```

it's really the same as

```
static const char hidden_C0[] = "line";
char *c = (char *)hidden_C0;
```

except that the variable `hidden_C0` is not directly accessible.  But you'll see it if you dump out generated assembly language (it will usually have a name that isn't a valid C identifier, like `.LC0`).  And in your array-of-string-constants example, the same thing is going on:

```
char *choices[] = { "New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit" };
```

becomes

```
const char hidden_C0[] = "New Game";
const char hidden_C1[] = "Continue Game";
const char hidden_C2[] = "Exit";

char *choices[] = { (char *)hidden_C0, (char *)hidden_C1, (char *)hidden_C2 };
```

Now, this is a special case behavior that is available *only* for string constants.  You cannot write

```
int *numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

you must write

```
int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

and that's why you can't write

```
char **choices = { "a", "b", "c" };
```

either.

(Your confusion is a special case of the common misconception that arrays are "the same as" pointers in C.  They are not.  Arrays are arrays.  Variables with array types suffer *type decay* to a pointer type when they are *used* (in almost every context), but not when they are defined.)

Answer (score 5):

It's ok, just write

`char **choices = (char *[]){ "New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit" };`

However, `choices` can be used only for linear addressing. For example:

`printf ("%s", &(*choices)[0]);` outputs: `New Game`
`printf ("%s", &(*choices)[1]);` outputs: `ew Game`
`printf ("%s", &(*choices)[9]);` outputs: `Continue Game`

So it's not a joke, it's a valid initialization. Just another kind of usage.

---

You can also find a very close example [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), explaining *Compound Literals* notion.

Comment: I'm all for *compound literals* but either this answer is a joke or I'm completely missing why you would do such a thing.

Comment: This expression compiles without any errors or warnings under GCC4.2. This question is about compiling problem, not usage

Comment: @SiegeX: I've updated my answer with examples of how this can be used

Comment: I should have been more specific with my comment. Why wouldn't you just declare 'choices' as `char *choices[] = { "New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit" };` ?

Answer (score 2):

Online C standard (draft [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)):

> **6.7.8 Initialization**
> ...
> 11 The initializer for a **scalar** shall be a **single expression**, optionally enclosed in braces. The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.
> ...
> 16 Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has **aggregate or union type** shall be a **brace enclosed list of initializers** for the elements or named members.

Emphasis added.

`char **` is a scalar type, not an aggregate, and so is not compatible with the initializer `{"New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit"}`.  By contrast, `char *[]` is an aggregate (array) type.

Similarly, you couldn't write something like

```
int *foo = {1, 2, 3};
```

because `int *` isn't an array type.

Your understanding of

```
char *c = "line";
```

and

```
char c[] = "line";
```

is slightly off; they are *not* the same.  The first form copies the *address* of the string literal to the pointer value `c`.  The second form copies the *contents* of the array expression `"line"` to the buffer designated by `c`.

Comment: people can only consider themselves true C developers after reading the whole C standard