# C Issue with understanding an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, memory

I did some google search on this already. The problem is I just find explanation what a char pointer or char pointer pointer does and simply what an array of char pointer is.
Actually my program is working. Simply when I close my eyes and accept everything the world is just fine but I constantly get some questions flashing in my mind, which I cant answer. Long story short I hope nobody will kill me for my question, since it could seem trivial to some of you,obviously it is not to me!
So her we go:

```
char *pc;
char **ppc;
char *string[2] = {"Hello","World",};
ppc = string;
pc = *ppc;


printf("%p\n",ppc);
printf("%p\n",&pc);
printf("%p\n",*ppc);   
printf("%p\n",pc);
printf("%p\n",&string[0]);  //or &string
printf("%c\n", **ppc);
printf("%s", *ppc);
```

after running this I was expecting *ppc to be the address of first string (first character of first string), which is not and I was also expecting kind of relation between &pc and ppc which is also not the case.
ppc is a pointer to pointer, but I literraly have no clue about the pointer which ppc is pointing before reaching the first element of string?
I am sorry if this all sounds stupid, but I really want to understand it. 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `*ppc` is the address of the first string - see the output of your last `printf`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832082/c-double-character-pointer-declaration-and-initialization. Lots of near duplicates available, if you'd search a little.

Comment: also, the `%p` expects a *pointer-to-void*, so you must cast each of these arguments to `(void*)`. Also, `&string[0]` and `&string` point to the same address, but different things. One says: "that's Mr. String", and the other "That's Mr. String's head".

Comment: All `%p` lines invoke undefined behaviour. Read the man-page carefully and use the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

Your code invokes Undefined Behavior, since `%p` excpets a pointr to void, thus *all* your print statements must cast their arguments to `void*`, like this for example `printf("%p\n", (void*) ppc);`.

Fix this and now draw your pointers, like this for example:

[image]

> I was expecting `*ppc` to be the address of first string (first character of first string), which is not

It is!

Check `printf("%p\n", (void*) ppc);` and `printf("%p\n", (void*) &string[0]);`-they produce the same output.

> I was also expecting kind of relation between `&pc` and `ppc`

- `ppc` has the address of the first string ("Hello").
- `*ppc` has the address of the first character of the string ('H').
- `pc` has the address of the first character of the string ('H').
- `&pc` has the address of `pc`.

So your expectation is false, `pc` and `*ppc` should have the same address, not `&pc`.

---

Further explanation:

`string` is an array of `char` pointers. `char **ppc;` is a double pointer to `char`.

Here:

```
ppc = string;
```

you set `ppc` to point to the address of the first element of `string`.

This:

```
pc = *ppc;
```

makes `pc` point to where `ppc` is actually pointing, that is the first element of `string`, i.e. `string[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

A picture etc. `char`s are yellow,  `char*` orange, `char**` blue
[image]

The letter 'e' can be obtained as `pc[1]`, `string[0][1]` `*ppc[1]` etc.

Comment: I like your image very much, the colors seem better than mine, nice answer! I have posted one as well, check it if you want! =)

Comment: There's an important detail : pc is the name of a "box" containing an address, string is the name of the _address_ where there are 2 consecutive boxes. C so-called "arrays" are historically a hack around pointers (constant ones, except when used as parameters) not really "variables".

Comment: @gsamaras I used "dia" under Linux

Answer (score 0):

The variable `string` is an array of pointers to characters, obviously it has to go somewhere, the actual array that is.

When you do

```
ppc = string;
```

you copy the address of the first element of `string` to `ppc`, and then

```
pc = *ppc;
```

copies the contents of that, i.e. the value of `string[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

After `ppc = string;`, `ppc` points to the first string of array `string`, i.e. it points to the string `"Hello"` (note that array `string` will decay to pointer to its first element in this case).

`*ppc` is a pointer that points to first character of the array `"Hello"`.
`pc = *ppc;` makes `pc` to point to the same character of the same string "Hello"`.

That makes:
*`ppc` will have address of the first string*.
*`*ppc` will have address of the first character of the first string*.

Comment: well that's the the question, are those the same?

Comment: No. They are not. `ppc` and `*ppc` are different though they have same address value.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `| |` are the values and inside `* *` are the addresses.

```
| H | E | L | L | O |
*100*

| W | O | R | L | D |
*200*

| 100 | 200 |   //string
 *300*
```

Now `ppc = string`, so

```
 ppc=>
       | 300 |
        *400*
```

Now `pc = *ppc`, so `pc = *300` which is `100`

```
 pc=>
      | 100 |
       *500*
```

Now if you do `printf("%s", pc);`, you will get the string stores at 100 which is `HELLO`.

Comment: Shouldn't `ppc=> | 100 |` be `ppc=> | 300 |`?

Comment: when you do `int a = b`, you want `a` to have value of `b`, so `ppc` points to what `string` points to.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused by your `ppc=>` notation. Is it supposed mean "this is the value of `ppc`", or "this is what `ppc` is pointing to"?

Comment: I realize it is misleading.`ppc=>` does not mean anything.It just says, do you want to see how `ppc` looks in memory?Go ahead and see below.

Comment: To me, it seems to indicate that `ppc` is stored at address 400 and contains the address 100. But it should contain the address 300 as that is the address of the first element of `string` in your diagram.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes. You are right.Thanks a lot  for the correction.